# Will I get iAd payments at all and when?

Tags: ios, iad

I have an app on the app store that has been out for a few months with iAd banners and I get a few dollars every month ( not very much ) and I heard that you need a minimum of revenue to actually get paid. if this is true, how much do I need? do they cumulative every month or do I need that minimum every month and therefore won't get any of the money I earned these past few months? thanks for your answers!

Comment: Due to currency and tax complexities, you need to accumulate enough money _in each country_ before getting paid for ad views each country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your revenue is cumulative. Check [this FAQ entry](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/41.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.1.1.1) for the payment schedule and minimums.

> When will I be paid?   Payments are made within 45 days of the last
>   day of the month in which app purchases were made. To receive payment,
>   you must have provided all required banking and tax information and
>   documentation, as well as meeting the minimum payment threshold.
>
> If your bank and bank account currency is listed in this table, you
>   must exceed a minimum payment threshold of $10 USD. All other bank
>   countries and bank account currencies must exceed a minimum payment
>   threshold of $150 USD.